# How would it change the game play style if players can see each other's racks in Scrabble?

Tags: scrabble

I've always been curious, and wanting to try this with a friend, but I don't know any real life friends that would play me. Also no apps that I know support it afaik, and you'd have to manually tell the person your rack each turn, which I doubt anyone is willing to try with me. I think it would make it more strategic although a prolonged game.

I was thinking a few things would change:

1. Each turn would take longer because each player is trying to counter the other one's moves.
2. In a game of 2 players, trying to block scoring opportunities for your opponent will have about as much weight as scoring high or rack management.
3. In a game of 3+ players, it won't have much of an effect until the endgame, because it takes a long enough time to figure out the best scoring or highest value play (a play that leaves with good tiles for next turn).
4. "Fishing" for letters may become a thing. If you notice all your opponent's racks contain no o's, the board contains few o's, but you need an o to make a bingo, you can probably assume there's a high chance of drawing an "o", so you use up only 1 tile or you exchange a tile when making a move now but score low points on the next turn would be less than exchanging tiles and scoring big next turn.

Comment: I think this would depend on the skill of the players in question

Comment: I agree with "In a game of 3+ players, it won't have much of an effect until the endgame", but I think there's a stronger reason than the one you pose: earning one point for yourself always has the same net effect as denying **each** of your opponents one point. So with one opponent, earning and denying are equally valuable, but with multiple opponents, earning becomes far more important than denying.

Answer (score 2):

### It would make gameplay more frustrating

There is very little to gain, and a lot to lose from this tweak.

1. Because players have more information available, it will take longer to decide what the optimal play is.
2. Because other players can see what you have, they are more likely to make moves that will block your best possible play.

Rather than encouraging strategic play, open information would instead encourage tactical play - you've added more information about what your opponents have right now, while adding comparatively little information about what will happen in the future.